# Connect to Tibco EMS using SSL java client

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, jms, tibco-ems

We are trying to connect to Tibco EMS using SSL (Java Client) with the following code

```java
factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
connection = factory.createConnection(userName,password);
```

I receive this error:

> Failed to connect via SSL to [ssl://host:8132]: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How to specify certification path to requested target?
I have C# client code with `EMSSSL.SetTargetHostName("UAT_5653")` but in java JMS dont know how to set

```java
com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.setExpectedHostName(ssl_hostname);
com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.setIdentity(ssl_identity,ssl_key,ssl_password);
com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.setVerifyHostName(false);
com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.addTrustedCerts(cert);
```

Comment: the error is about cert path. What is in "cert" variable? it should be path to cert file like com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.addTrustedCerts("c:\\server_cert.pem");  You may also need to add certificate to java keystore https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html

Comment: thanks David, i disabled verification host  by  factory.setSSLEnableVerifyHost(false);   factory.setSSLEnableVerifyHostName(false);,its give me make connection

Comment: @Rudy disabling host verification means your SSL connection is not really secure. You can easily be victim of Man-In-The-Middle-attacks.

Answer (score 1):

These parameters can be set in the factory object like:

```
TibjmsConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
factory.setSSLExpectedHostName(ssl_expected_hostname);
factory.setSSLIdentity(ssl_identity,ssl_key,ssl_password);
factory.setSSLEnableVerifyHostName(false);
factory.setSSLTrustedCertificate(cert);
Connection connection = factory.createConnection(userName,password);
```

For more information you might take a look at the [docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/8.1.0/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/TibjmsConnectionFactory.html).

Comment: Hi @pascalre, we are trying to connect to JMS server with SSL. WE followed the same set of lines,
we are getting the below error, can you please help us

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to start JMS source task: 1 Failed to establish JMS connectivity: 2 Failed to establish JMS connectivity: Failed to connect to any server at: ssl://buwnwfblapp01.nw1.nwestnetwork.com:7243,ssl://buwnwfblapp01.nw1.nwestnetwork.com:7243...

Comment: @Thebestshoot you can get more details about your problem by adding these two lines of code:
factory.setSSLTrace(true);
factory.setSSLDebugTrace(true);